# Tensorflow Gradient Descent bug: weights aren't changing and cost set to 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I tried to build a convolutional neural network but I have stumbled over some really strange problems.

first thing's first, here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob

x = []
y = 1

for filename in glob.glob('trainig_data/*.jpg'):
    im = mpimg.imread(filename)
    x.append(im)
    if len(x) == 10:
        break
epochs = 5

weights = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,32],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,64,128],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([75*75*128,1064],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1064,1],0.1))]

def CNN(x, weights):
    output = tf.nn.conv2d([x], weights[0], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[1], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[2], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1,75*75*128])
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[3])
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[4])
    output = tf.reduce_sum(output)
    return output


sess = tf.Session()
prediction = CNN(tf.cast(x[0],tf.float32), weights)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction-y))
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)
for e in range(epochs):
    print('epoch:',e+1)
    for x_i in x:
        prediction = CNN(tf.cast(x_i,tf.float32), weights)
        sess.run([cost, train])
        print(sess.run(cost))
print('optimization finished!')
print(sess.run(prediction))
```

Now here are my problems:

1. The values of the weights and filters are not changing
2. The variable 'cost' is always 1.0
3. The prediction always puts out a 0

After doing some debugging I found out that the problem must come from the optimizer, because the cost and the prediction are not 1.0 and 0 before I put the weights trough the optimizer.

I hope that was enough information and that you can help me with my problem.

PS. I already tried using `tf.truncated_normal` instead of `tf.random_normal`

Comment: There's clearly something wrong with the inputs and how you're feeding them. Have you checked what's in `x` before creating the session?

Comment: x is a list filled with numpy arrays

Comment: I understand that part, but will you let us know its concrete dimensions? You might be passing it to the network incorrectly.

Comment: batches*width*height*channels
or in other words 10*300*300*3

Answer (score 2):

I think I get the problem with the code. You need to define placeholders to feed your input, you don't have any placeholders. You are passing a tensorflow casting of a constant value (first image) x[0] to the model. Your code defines a new tensorflow computation graph everytime when you call prediction = CNN(...) in each epoch. Overall, you are defining a model each time, feeding it a constant image. Here is a link to define a TensorFlow CNN model for MNIST images that I had prepared before: 
https://github.com/dipendra009/MNIST_TF-Slim/blob/master/MNIST_TensorFlow.ipynb
. I hope it helps. Also, please look at the TensorFlow documentation for placeholders, that will help you understand it better.

Comment: This is my improved training code:


`for e in range(epochs):
    print('epoch:',e+1)
    for x_i in x:
        sess.run([cost, train], feed_dict={x_p:x_i})
        print(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x_p:x_i}))
print('optimization finished!')`


But nothing changed

Comment: You have to define placeholders in the graph to take the inputs. Did you look at the link I shared: https://github.com/dipendra009/MNIST_TF-Slim/blob/master/MNIST_TensorFlow.ipynb

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what you mean by "defining the placeholders in the graph"

Comment: Define placeholders like this:train_data_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, NUM_CHANNELS))
train_labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape= (BATCH_SIZE,))
eval_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(EVAL_BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, NUM_CHANNELS)). Then use it to define your model like: logits = model(train_data_node, True). And then run the model as: feed_dict = {train_data_node: batch_data, train_labels_node: batch_labels}
        _, l, lr, predictions = sess.run([optimizer, loss, learning_rate, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict).

Comment: That didn't change anything

Comment: Did you try to run the code I shared and reproduce the results? Once you are able to get the same results as the one on ipython notebook I shared, try to replace the MNIST dataset with yours and that should work. Give it some try :)

Comment: it only puts out this: `Initialized
Test error: 100.0%`
I'm beginning to think I'm cursed